# NULL pointer while sending request with two parameters to a service

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, postman

i'm trying to send two objects from postman to a service in spring boot application and this is the response of the request

```
{
    "timestamp": 1585855140707,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.NullPointerException",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/registerAdmin"
}
```

This is the method in the controller

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("Admin")
    AdministratorManager manager = new AdministratorManager();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST  , value = "/registerAdmin")
    public boolean registerAdmin(@RequestParam(required = false, name = "user1") User user1, @RequestParam(required = false, name = "user2") User user2) throws SQLException {

        return manager.addUser(user1, user2);
    }
```

and the service

```
public boolean addUser(User user1, User user2) throws SQLException {
        if(isRegisterd(user1))
        {
            if(isRegisterd(user2))
            {
                return false; // this administrator already exist.
            }
            else
            {
                Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnectoin();
                PreparedStatement stmt;
                try {
                    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Administrator(Name, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                    stmt.setString(1, user2.getName());
                    stmt.setString(2, user2.getPassword());
                    stmt.setString(3, user2.getEmail());
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                    return true;
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First guess: user1 or user2 could be null. Please add exception message to get a more detailed answer.

Edit:
You get an internal Server error. I am guessing that user2 is NULL. You are not checkong that but using `user2.getName()`. Please check and tell me if this was the reason.

Comment: how come?
[
 {
     "type": "Admin",
  "email": "a",
     "name": "Hussein",
     "password": "crimson"
 }
 ,
 {
     "type": "Admin",
     "email": "aaaa",
     "name": "omar",
     "password": "Hunter"
 }
]

Comment: No, please send the NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION that you get

Comment: i'm sorry for this representation , my point is the objects should filled with these attributes

Comment: i set the message in the first section of the question